# Examine phase portrait $(f,f')$ for $f"+vf'+\alpha^2f(1-f)=0$ and determine asymptotic behavious of solutions as $x\to \pm \infty$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

> Find the travelling wave solutions, in the form $u(x,t)=f(x-vt)$, of *Fisher's equation* $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+a^2u(1-u)$$ where $a>0$ is a constant. Investigate the nature of these solutions by examining the phase-plane $(f,f')$ and show, in particular, that there exist solutions such that $f\to0$ as $x\to-\infty$, $f\to1$ as $x\to\infty$, for all $v\le-2a$.
>
> This equation originally arose in a theory of genuine selection in a species (in a paper by Fisher, 1937). It also arise in the theory of combustion, and chemical kinetics.

I have the Fisher equation:
$$u_t=u_{xx}+\alpha^2u(1-u)$$
I use the ansatz $u=f(x-vt)$ so that the DE turns into
$$f''+vf'+\alpha^2f(1-f)=0$$
Then I define $x_1=f$ and $x_2=f'$ so that:
$$   \left( \begin{array}{cc} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{array} \right)'= \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1  \\ -\alpha^2(1-x_1) & -v  \end{array} \right)     \left( \begin{array}{cc} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{array} \right)$$
Now I need to examine the nature of the solutions $f$ by examining the phase portrait for $(x_1,x_2)$ and in particular show that there exists solutions such that $f\to0$ as $x\to -\infty$ and $f\to 1$ as $f\to \infty$ for all $v\leq 2\alpha$.

I am not sure how to examine the phase portrait here because I have no experience drawing them for non-linear two-dimensional system of differential equations. Also, I am not sure how to show the desired solution exist satisfying $f\to0$ as $x\to -\infty$ and $f\to 1$ as $f\to \infty$ for all $v\leq 2\alpha$. If anyone could help me in solving or give me some hints I would be very grateful. Also if anyone knows of a free software package that can draw phase portraits like this for me I would be very happy. Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

NOTE: I decided to not change to $x_1$ and $x_2$ but just keep $f$ and $f'$ instead.

Now $f'' = -\alpha^2f(1-f)  -vf'$, then we can write:
$$   \left( \begin{array}{cc} f \\ f' \end{array} \right)'= \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1  \\ -\alpha^2(1-f) & -v  \end{array} \right)     \left( \begin{array}{cc} f \\ f' \end{array} \right)$$\
We can find the stationary points by setting 
$$ \left( \begin{array}{cc} f \\ f' \end{array} \right)' = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1  \\ -\alpha^2(1-f) & -v  \end{array} \right)     \left( \begin{array}{cc} f \\ f' \end{array} \right) =  \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 \\ 0 \end{array} \right)$$
This immediately gives us $f'=0$ and $\alpha^2(1-f)f=0$, so $f$ is either $0$ or $1$. This gives the stationary points for $(f,f')$ as $(1,0)$ and $(0,0)$. Now we can compute the Jacobian in these points, first we write:
$$ \left( \begin{array}{cc} f \\ f' \end{array} \right)' = F(f,f') =  \left( \begin{array}{cc} f' \\ -\alpha^2(1-f)f -vf' \end{array} \right)$$
So the Jacobian $J(F)$ is:
$$J(F)=\left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1  \\ -\alpha^2(1-2f) & -v  \end{array} \right)  $$
So that:

$$J(F(0,0))=F_{0,0}=\left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1  \\ -\alpha^2 & -v  \end{array} \right)\ \ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ \ \  J(F(1,0))=F_{1,0}=\left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1  \\ \alpha^2 & -v  \end{array} \right)  $$
Now we can calculate their eigenvalues using the characteristic polynomials and setting it to 0:
$$\det\left(\lambda I -F_{0,0}\right)      =   \left| \begin{array}{cc} \lambda & -1  \\ \alpha^2 & \lambda+v  \end{array} \right| = \lambda^2 +v\lambda + \alpha^2 = 0 $$
This gives us the eigenvalues of $F$ in the stationary point $(0,0)$ as:
$$\lambda_{1,2}(F_{0,0}) = \frac{-v \pm \sqrt{  v^2 - 4\alpha^2 }}{2}$$
Similarly 
$$\det\left(\lambda I -F_{1,0}\right)      =   \left| \begin{array}{cc} \lambda & -1  \\ -\alpha^2 & \lambda+v  \end{array} \right| = \lambda^2 +v\lambda - \alpha^2 = 0 $$
So
$$\lambda_{1,2}(F_{1,0}) = \frac{-v \pm \sqrt{  v^2 + 4\alpha^2 }}{2}$$

I have a feeling this is incorrect though, because using $v \leq -2\alpha <  0$ both eigenvalues have positve real part which makes them unstable... Also, the fact that im looking for $v \leq -2\alpha (<0) $ leads me to believe that I need to have we need a positive discriminant. This would of course also be the case if $v>2\alpha$ but then $v$ is positive which I guess we dont want. Thanks for any help. I am sorry if this is unclear, plz ask any questions if you would like to know more!! Thanks

2ND UPDATE:
Starting here:
$$ \left( \begin{array}{cc} f \\ f' \end{array} \right)' = F(f,f')=\left( \begin{array}{cc} f_1(x,t) \\ f_2(x,t) \end{array} \right) =  \left( \begin{array}{cc} f'(x,t) \\ -\alpha^2[f(x,t)-f(x,t)^2] -vf'(x,t) \end{array} \right)$$
Remembering that $f=f(x-vt)$, then using the chain rule in a fairly straight forward manner we find that the Jacobian is given by:
$$\left(     \begin{array}{cc} \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial t}\\  \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial t}
\end{array}   \right)  =     \left(    \begin{array}{cc}  f'' & -vf'' \\ -\alpha^2(f'-2f) -vf'' & v\alpha^2(f'-2f) +  v^2f''
\end{array}    \right)$$
We have already found that $f'' = -vf' - \alpha^2(f-f^2)$. At the stationary points $(f,f') =(1,0)$ or $(0,0)$ we find that $f''= 0$. Thus at $(1,0)$ the Jacobian is:
$$ F_{(1,0)}= \left(    \begin{array}{cc}  0 & 0 \\ 2\alpha^2  & -2v\alpha^2 
\end{array}    \right)$$
And at $(f,f')=(0,0)$ the Jacobian is:
$$F_{(0,0)} =  \left(    \begin{array}{cc}  0 & 0 \\ 0  & 0 
\end{array}    \right)$$
So we find the eigenvalues:
$$\det(\lambda I - F_{(1,0)})   =   \left|    \begin{array}{cc}  \lambda & 0 \\ -2\alpha^2  & \lambda -2v\alpha^2 
\end{array}    \right| = \lambda^2 - \lambda2 v\alpha^2 $$
So we have a repeated eigenvalue $\lambda_{(1,0)}=2v\alpha^2$.

For the stationary point $(0,0)$ the eigenvalues of the Jacobian is $\lambda_{(0,0)}=0$ repeated.
Is this right? I am not sure how to continue form here... I worry that because I am using the notation $f'$ and then differentiating w.r.t. both $x$ and $t$ later on that I might be making mistakes. What I am using is that $f=f(\eta)$ where $\eta =x-vt$ and thus we can just write $f'$ and still differentiate w.r.t. $x$ and $t$ by using the chain rule.

Comment: Not really i am afraid. The stationary points are easy to find, however the rest is quite difficult. This piece of homework is due next tuesday so I will post an update tuesday or earlier! Thanks for the interest

Comment: You mean drawing the phase portrait and seeing the behaviors?

Comment: Well I plotted the phase portraits by plotting them as a vector field. The problem lies in showing a solution exists where $f\to 0$ as $x\to -\infty$ and $f\to 1$ as $x\to \infty$. I think I might have to look at the eigenvalues of $\left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1  \\ -\alpha^2(1-x_1) & -v  \end{array} \right)   $

Comment: Did you find the critical points, then the Jacobian matrix and then evaluate the eigenvalues of the Jacobian for each critical point? You should of course see the behaviors in the vector field plot too.

Comment: I made an update with Jacobian and eigenvalues at the critical points, however they are not giving me the desired outcome... Please find my update on the question above! Thanks for your input!

Comment: You are very close with your analysis and did great work. Have you thought about dimensionless units? See Ex 3.1 at http://www.math.colostate.edu/~pauld/M546/TWS3.pdf Regards

Comment: I found a mistake I made. when I determined the jacobian i differentiated with respect to $f$ and $f'$ which makes no sense, I should have differentiated with respect to $x$ and $t$. This still however doesnt solve my problem because when I do this I get a jacobian that is only zeros at the stationary points...

Comment: Can you post that update so we can have a look? Regards

Comment: I am working on typing it out right now! I will send an update as soon as it is done! thanks for the interest!

Comment: I posted my update above!

Comment: How do you know the values of $f(0,0)$ and $f(1,0)$? Recall, we have $f(x,t)$ here. The Jacobian is $J(x,t)$.

Comment: Isn't it the case that in these stationary points I do not know the value of $x$ and $t$ but I do know the value of $f$ and $f'$. The subscript $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$ were meant to indicate at which stationary point the Jacobian was evaluated. Maybe I am making an oversight here though..

Comment: If you write $x'=x(3-x-2y), y'=y(3-x-y)$, you find four critical points. The Jacobian changes at each of the 4 critical points $(0,0),(0,2),(3,0),(1,1)$, for example.

Comment: I asked this question again where I posted bounty for it. Feel free to have a look! http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/535768/show-fvf-alpha2-f1-f-0-has-solutions-satisfying-lim-x-to-infty

Answer (score 1):

**HINT** First off, always find the steady states/fixed points/equilibria of your system
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
x_1' &=& x_2 ,
\\
x_2' &=& -\alpha^2 x_1(1-x_1) - \nu x_2 .
\end{array}
$$
Plainly, the only fixed points are $(0,0)$ & $(1,0)$, corresponding to the limit behavior of the solution you're looking for. So, you're looking for a heteroclinic connection from the former to the latter. You might want to consider the energy of the Hamiltonian system ($\nu=0$), namely $H=\frac{1}{2}\dot{x}^2+ \alpha^2 \left(\frac{1}{2}x^2 - \frac{1}{3}x^3\right)$, and you might also want to check the Fife & McLeod paper(s) for references & results. Are you sure you have the directionality of the solution right, btw? Also, your ineq. is problematic - the Hamiltonian case $\nu=0$ falls within your regime, but the two fixed points are on different energy levels & thus cannot connect. Check again.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The inequality was given in the question so I guess it is required. I posted an update above in which I found that when $v \leq 2\alpha $ the eigenvalues are purely real, so they do not oscillate which I guess makes sense because the solution I am looking for is contained between 0 and 1. Please find my update above!

Comment: Thanks Teun, let me look @ it over the weekend, I'd like to know myself how it's proved. Was this really given as a HW problem @ RUG? Who's giving the class?!

Comment: Yeah this is a HW assignment. We are supposed to do a lot of figuring out ourselves, it is not the case that our reading material/lectures cover all we need which is quite new for me. I added an Imgur link in my question to the original question (this was the best way I could think of)

Comment: I reasked this question for bounty. Feel free to have a look and try to answer if you are still interested :) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/535768/show-fvf-alpha2-f1-f-0-has-solutions-satisfying-lim-x-to-infty

Comment: Normally I would, but there are far more pressing issues at hand right now :). Succes met de rest van je studie!

Comment: hehe bedankt! even so you can always have a look because some nice answers have been given!