# Show $f''+vf' +\alpha^2 f(1-f)=0$ has solutions satisfying $\lim_{x \to - \infty}f=0$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty}f=1$ given $v\leq -2\alpha < 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I posted this question before but I took a completely different approach here, that's why I reposted as my previous question was already very long and took a different approach from here.

I am given the Fisher equation $$u_t=u_{xx}+\alpha ^2u(1-u)$$ where $\alpha >0$ is a constant. Now assuming that $u(x,t) = f(x-vt)$ I need to show there exists a solution $f$ such that $\lim\limits_{x \to - \infty}f=0$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to  \infty}f=1$ provided that $v \leq -2\alpha$. Now substituting $f$ into the differential equation we get:
$$f''+vf' +\alpha^2 f(1-f)=0$$
Where $f$ is a funtion of a single variable $\eta = x-vt$.

From here onwards I will go into my attempt to solve using linearization about the stationary points. If someone finds another method to show the asked results I will still award the bounty!

It is easy to see that the two stationary points are $(f_0,f'_0)=(0,0)$ and $(f_1,f'_1)=(1,0)$. Now I will linearize the system in these stationary points, first in $(f_0,f'_0)$ via $f=f_0 +\epsilon w_0$ around the first stationary points. Leaving out terms of order $\epsilon^2$ we obtain the following differential equation via substituting this $f$:
$$w_0''+vw'_0+\alpha^2 w_0=0        $$
The solution to this DE is $w_0=Ae^{r_1 \eta}+Be^{r_2 \eta}$ where $r_1 = \frac{-v + \sqrt{v^2-4\alpha^2}}{2}$ and $r_2 = \frac{-v - \sqrt{v^2-4\alpha^2}}{2}$. Now using $v \leq -2\alpha < 0$ we see that $0 \leq \sqrt{v^2-4\alpha^2}< -v$ such that $-v + \sqrt{v^2-4\alpha^2}$ and $-v-\sqrt{v^2-4\alpha^2 }$ are both larger than zero. Thus around the stationary point $(f,f')=(0,0)$ we can approximate the solution of $f$ by:
$$f = f_0 + w_0 = Ae^{r_1 \eta}+Be^{r_2 \eta}$$
Where both $r_1$ and $r_2$ are positive, thus $f$ is increasing at the stationary point $(f,f')=(0,0)$. This is the first result.

Now for the second stationary point we use the linearization $f=f_1+\epsilon w_1 = 1 + \epsilon w_1$. This turns the DE into:
$$w_0''+vw'_0-\alpha^2 w_0=0        $$
with solution $w_1=Ce^{s_1\eta}+De^{s_2\eta}$
where $s_1 = \frac{-v + \sqrt{v^2+4\alpha^2}}{2} > 0$ and $s_2=\frac{-v - \sqrt{v^2+4\alpha^2}}{2}<0$
So the approximation around $(f,f')=(1,0)$ is given by $$f=f_1+ Ce^{s_1\eta}+De^{s_2\eta}=1+Ce^{s_1\eta}+De^{s_2\eta}$$
which can be either increasing or decreasing, I cant tell unless we determine the constants.

My question is, how do I proceed from here. I think I am going in the right direction as I heard from some of my classmates they solved the problem using linearization... I realize that even the conclusion that the first approximation is increasing is shaky because then I am making the assumption that $A$ and $B$ are not both negative... If anyone could help me out that would be amazing. This question is homework but the deadline is already passes, I handed in what I had and did good on the other questions. I am just frustrated by my inability to get anywhere with this question no matter how much time I spend on it... Thanks in advance!

P.S. if anyone has a better way of solving that would of course be very welcome too! Thanks

Comment: To Slugger:  It appears to me that your (linearized) equation for $f$, $f=f_1+ Ce^{s_1}+De^{s_2}=1+Ce^{s_1}+De^{s_2}$, is missing a factor of $\eta$ in the exponentials, and should perhaps read $f=f_1+ Ce^{s_1 \eta}+De^{s_2 \eta}=1+Ce^{s_1 \eta}+De^{s_2 \eta}$.  I see that a similar concern applies to your other linearizazations as well.  Am I right?  Does this fine point help clarify your understanding of the situation at all, or are we merely correcting a typo?  It's OK either way.  To be continued . . .

Comment: To Slugger:  What I meant in my last comment is that I can see how your progress might be impeded if you mistook $f=f_1+ Ce^{s_1}+De^{s_2}=1+Ce^{s_1}+De^{s_2}$, which is a constant, for the linearization $f=f_1+ Ce^{s_1 \eta}+De^{s_2 \eta}=1+Ce^{s_1 \eta}+De^{s_2 \eta}$, which is not!  Just trying to help out . . .

Comment: @RobertLewis Thanks a lot for this comment! It is indeed a typo and I will correct it. Mental fatigue setting in at the time of writing because I had been at it for ages :) Thanks for the keen observation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Added 31 October 2013 11:48 PM PST:***  The following, yet ***another*** answer, is added as such for the same reasons given in my second:  it is too long for the comments, and after trying to edit it into *that* answer, and waiting a full two hours while mathjax attempted to render my work, I resorted to breaking up my post(s) into separate answers once again, though they should in fact be considered *of a piece*, as the saying goes.  And again, I beg my readers' indulgence.

Since posting my second answer, which as I explained should really be considered an integral part of my first, I think I have found a way to get substantially closer to finishing this thing off, in the sense of showing that there is indeed a heteroclinic trajectory $\gamma(\eta)$ such that $\lim_{\eta \to -\infty}\gamma(\eta) = (0, 0)$ and $\lim_{\eta \to \infty}\gamma(\eta) = (1, 0)$.  The construction presented in the above discussion, albeit somewhat "hand-wavy", is meant to demonstrate that the necessary existence of a heteroclinic orbit may be mollified by the presence of periodic trajectories; if we can eliminate the possibility that such occur, I think we will be one step closer to a position from which the existence of the sought-for heteroclinic orbit is within reach.

So here we will show that the vector field $F(f, g)$ has no periodic trajectories.  This can be handled by the old method of Bendixson; see [this wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bendixson%E2%80%93Dulac_theorem) or [this book by Gerald Teschl](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~gerald/ftp/book-ode/ode.pdf), the seventh chapter.  (The same book is mentioned in my first answer above.)  The relevant technique is as follows:  suppose $V(f, g)$ is any $C^1$ vector field in the $f$-$g$ plane $\Bbb R^2$, and let $\Omega  \subset \Bbb R^2$ be open and simply connected such that $\nabla \cdot V = \frac{\partial V_f}{\partial f} + \frac{\partial V_g}{\partial g} \ne 0$ on $\Omega$; then $V(f, g)$ can have no periodic orbit in $\Omega$.  To see this, we look at the integral of $\nabla \cdot V$ over a region bounded by such a closed trajectory, assuming one existed, and use the divergence theorem of Gauss in its two-dimensional form, thusly: if $F(f, g)$ has a periodic trajectory $\gamma(\eta)$ in the simply connected region $\Omega$, it bounds some also open simply connected region $\Gamma \subset \Omega$; we then have, since $\nabla \cdot V \ne 0$ on $\Omega$, it is either *positive* or *negative* on *all* of $\Omega$, hence on all of $\Gamma$ as well.  Thus

$\int_\Gamma (\nabla \cdot V) dfdg \ne 0; \tag{1}$

but by Gauss's theorem we have

$\int_\Gamma (\nabla \cdot V) dfdg = \int_{\gamma(\eta)} (V \cdot n)ds; \tag{2}$

but

$\int_{\gamma(\eta)} (V \cdot n)ds = 0, \tag{3}$

since $n$ is the outward pointing normal on $\gamma(\eta)$ and $V$ is tangent to $\gamma(\eta)$; thus $V \cdot n = 0$.  This contradiction proves that $V(f, g)$ has no closed trajectories.  To apply these notions to $F(f, g)$, recall from my *first* answer that the Jacobean of $F(f, g)$ is

$J_F = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -\alpha^2(1 - 2 f) & -v \end{bmatrix}, \tag{4}$

whence we have

$\nabla \cdot F = \text{Tr}(J_F) = -v > 0, \, v \, \text{a constant}, \tag{5}$

which in light of the above precludes the possibility of the existence of a periodic trajectory of $F$. Apparently the same argument precludes the existence of a homoclinic orbit joining $(1, 0)$ to itself. i.e, of $W_u(1, 0) = W_s(1, 0)$; the integral over $\gamma(\eta)$ in such as case is well-defined except on a set of measure zero, that being the point $(1, 0)$ itself, where $W_s(1, 0)$ and $W_u(1, 0)$ intersect but have different (non-collinear) tangent vectors.

I seems to me that at this point we are left with the following situation:  the integral curve $\gamma(\eta)$ such that $\gamma(\eta) \to (1, 0)$ as $\eta \to \infty$ cannot, as $\eta \to -\infty$, either loop back to $(1, 0)$ itself (case of $\gamma(\eta)$ homoclinic) or approach a periodic orbit, since there are none.  Furthermore, there is no *cycle* of equilibria and heteroclinic orbits, since $(0, 0)$ is a purely repelling point; no integral curve can enter it as $\eta \to \infty$.  So by the [Poincare-Bendixson theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Bendixson_theorem), we are left with two prospects:  either $\gamma(\eta) \to (0, 0)$ as $\eta \to -\infty$, or $\gamma(\eta)$ leaves any compact set in $\Bbb R^2$.  Now if I could just rule out this latter possibility . . .

Ah well, Happy Halloween, my friends!

Hope this helps ***just a little bit more***.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 3):

First of all, "solving" the given equation,

$f''+vf' + \alpha^2 f(1-f)=0, \tag{1}$

appears to be quite a challenge, if by solving we mean deriving a closed form, analytical expression for $f(\eta)$.  Nevertheless, a great deal may be said about the qualitative features of the solutions to (1); in particular, the OP's specific inquiry into the existence of solutions $f(\eta) = f(x - vt)$ such that $\lim_{x \to - \infty}f(x - vt) = 0$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x - vt) = 1$ may be rigorously answered in the affirmative, provided one is willing to invoke some deeper results from the theory of ordinary differential equations and/or dynamical systems.  I am thinking here of the so-called *stable manifold theorem* and related results, which affirm that linearizations of a non-linear differential equation at *hyperbolic equilibrium points*, that is, those at which the Jacobean has no eigenvalue with vanishing real part, accurately describe the local dynamics of the original, non-linear system in the following, specific sense:  let

$\dot y = G(y) \tag{2}$

be an autonomous ordinary differential equation defined on an open $\Omega \subset \Bbb R^n$ with $G \in C^1(\Omega, \Bbb R^n)$, and let $y_0 \in \Omega$ be an equilibrium point of $G$:  $G(y_0) = 0$.  Suppose that $DG(y_0)$ has $k$ eigenvalues with negative real part and $n - k$ eigenvalues with positive real part; then the subspace $E_s$ of tangent vectors to $\Bbb R^n$ at $y_0$ spanned by the $k$ eigenvectors of $DG(y_0)$ corresponding to the eigenvalues with negative real part is in fact the tangent space at $y_0$ to a submanifold $W_s$ of $\Bbb R^n$ in $\Omega$ having the property that, for any $y_1 \in W_s$, $\lim_{t \to \infty} \phi_t(y_1) = y_0$, where $\phi_t$ is the flow of the vector field $G(y)$; similarly, the subspace $E_u$ spanned by the $n - k$ eigenvectors corresponding to eigenvalues with positive real part is tangent to a submanifold $W_u$ such that $\lim_{t \to -\infty} \phi_t(y_1) = y_0$ for $y_1 \in W_u$.  This result tells us that the essential local stability  features of the flow $\psi_t$ of the linearized system

$\dot y = DG(y_0)y \tag{3}$

are in fact manifested in the flow of the nonlinear equation (2) in the sense that families of solutions of (3) which lie in the linear subspaces $E_s$, $E_u$ correspond to families of solutions of (2) which lie in the nonlinear subspaces $W_s$, $W_u$, at least locally near $y_0$.  $W_s$ is called the *stable manifold* of the point $y_0$; likewise, $W_u$ is termed the *unstable manifold*. The demonstrations of these results are decidedly non-elementary but invoking them, or something similar,  is the only way I know to *prove*, rigorously, that the sought-for solutions to (1) indeed do exist.

The brief synopsis of stable manifold theory presented in the preceding paragaph is hopefully sufficient to complete the arguments given below; more detail may be found in any of several online resources; see for example [this wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_manifold_theorem) as well as [these lecture notes](https://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/wiki/images/b/ba/Cds140a-wi11-Week4Notes.pdf) and [this book](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~gerald/ftp/book-ode/ode.pdf), both of which are available for free online as downloadable texts.

These things being said, we define a new dependent variable

$g(\eta) = f'(\eta), \tag{4}$

and proceed as follows:  equation (1) may now be written as a two-dimensional, first order system consisting of (4) and

$g'(\eta) = -vg(\eta) - \alpha^2 f(\eta)(1-f(\eta)); \tag{5}$

taken together, (4) and (5) may be thought of as a vector field $F(f, g)$ in the $f$-$g$ plane $\Bbb R^2$:

$F(f, g) = \begin{pmatrix} F_f \\ F_g \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} g \\ -v g - \alpha^2 f(1-f) \end{pmatrix}, \tag{6}$

and then our differential equation becomes

$\begin{pmatrix} f \\ g \end{pmatrix}' = F(f, g) = \begin{pmatrix} g \\ -vg - \alpha^2 f(1-f) \end{pmatrix}. \tag{7}$

We investigate the flow of (7) in the $f$-$g$ plane.  In accord with the usual procedure, we first find the equilibrium points or zeroes of $F(f, g)$; setting

$F(f, g) = \begin{pmatrix} g \\ -vg - \alpha^2 f(1-f) \end{pmatrix} = 0, \tag{8}$

it is easily seen that these zeroes occur at the points $(f, g) = (0, 0)$, $(f, g) = (1, 0)$.  The qualitative aspects of the flow of $F$ in the vicinity of either of these points may be investigated *via* the Jacobean matrix $J_F$ of $F$; we have

$J_F = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -\alpha^2(1 - 2 f) & -v \end{bmatrix} \tag{9}$

since

$J_F = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial F_f}{\partial f} & \frac{\partial F_f}{\partial g} \\ \frac{\partial F_g}{\partial f} & \frac{\partial F_g}{\partial g} \end{bmatrix}. \tag{10}$

At $(f, g) = (0, 0)$, we obtain

$J_F(0, 0) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -\alpha^2 & -v \end{bmatrix}; \tag{11}$

the eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $J_F(0, 0)$ satisfy

$\lambda^2 + v \lambda + \alpha^2 = 0, \tag{12}$

whence we have

$\lambda_\pm = \frac{1}{2}(-v \pm \sqrt{v^2 - 4\alpha^2}). \tag{13}$

Applying the condition $v \le -2\alpha < 0$ to (12) reveals that, since $v^2 > v^2 - 4\alpha^2 \ge 0$, both $\lambda_\pm > 0$; $(0, 0)$ is thus a purely repelling equilibrium point; any solution starting sufficiently close to to $(0, 0)$ will move away from that location as $\eta$ increases.  Similarly, as $\eta \to - \infty$, any initial point sufficiently close to $(0, 0)$ will satisfy $(f(\eta), g(\eta)) \to (0, 0)$; in particular we have that $\lim_{\eta \to - \infty}f(\eta) = 0$; and since $\eta = x - vt$, $x \to \pm \infty$ imples $\eta \to \pm \infty$ (assuming $t$ is fixed); thus $\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = 0$.  When $(f, g) = (1, 0)$, on the other hand, we find that

$J_F(1, 0) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ \alpha^2 & -v \end{bmatrix}, \tag{14}$

and the eigenvalues satisfy the quadratic

$\lambda^2 + v \lambda -\alpha^2 = 0, \tag{15}$

the roots of which are

$\lambda_\pm = \frac{1}{2}(-v \pm \sqrt{v^2 + 4\alpha^2}); \tag{16}$

in this case, since $v^2 + 4\alpha^2 > v^2$, we see that the two eigenvalues are of opposite signs; therefore the point $(1, 0)$ is a saddle, and corresponding to the negative eigenvalue $\lambda_-$ there is a trajectory $\gamma(\eta) = (f(\eta), g(\eta))$ of $F(f, g)$ such that $\lim_{\eta \to \infty} \gamma(\eta) = (1, 0)$; for such an integral curve of $F$, $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \lim_{\eta \to \infty} f(\eta) = 1$.  We have thus established the existence of the two types of solutions the question requires.

***Established the existence***, that is, save for one tacit *caveat*:  in the preceding paragraph we linearized the system (7) about each of it's two critical points and then *implicitly* invoked stable manifold theory as described above to show that the behavior of the solutions to (7) in the vicinity of its critical point is essentially the same as that of these linearizations.  While this line of reasoning is appealing to the intuition, it leaves a gap in rigor which needs to be addressed to obtain a complete solution.  This gap may be closed by providing a more detailed explanation of the application of stable manifold theory to the equation (1) in neighborhoods of the zeroes of the equivalent, two-dimensional system (7).  Taking first the zero $(0, 0)$ of $F(f, g)$, we recall we found the Jacobean has two positive, real eigenvalues at this point; thus the hypothesis of the stable manifold theorem are fulfilled, and we clearly have $\dim E_u = 2$; thus $\dim W_u = 2$ as well; $\dim E_s = \dim W_s = 0$ in this case; $E_s$ is the subspace $\{0\}$ of the tangent space to $\Bbb R^2$ at $(0, 0)$, and $W_s$ is the point $(0, 0)$ itself, a submanifold of dimension $0$.  $W_u$, being of dimension $2$ in $\Bbb R^2$, is in fact an open set containing $(0, 0)$, and since $\phi_\eta((f_1, g_1)) \to (0, 0)$ as $\eta \to -\infty$ for every $(f_1, g_1) \in W_u$, where $\phi_\eta$ is the flow of $F(f, g)$, we see that the theory of stable manifolds affirms the above assertion that there exist solutions $f(\eta)$ to (1) satisfying $\lim_{\eta \to -\infty}f(\eta) = 0$, and this of course implies $\lim_{x \to -\infty}f(x) = 0$ since $\eta = x - vt$ (and again, we hold $t$ fixed).  Turning now the critical point $(1, 0)$, we found in the preceding paragraph that the eigenvalues of $DF(1, 0)$ are $\lambda_\pm = \frac{1}{2}(-v \pm \sqrt{v^2 + 4\alpha^2})$, one positive and one negative, since $v^2 + 4\alpha^2 > v^2$.  Again invoking the stable manifold theorem, we see that $\dim E_s = \dim W_s = 1$ and also that $\dim E_u = \dim W_u = 1$; for any $(f_1, g_1) \in W_s$, $\phi_\eta((f_1, g_1)) \to (1, 0)$ as $\eta \to \infty$, hence $\phi_x((f_1, g_1)) \to (1, 0)$ as $x \to \infty$, and so we must have $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 1$ for any solution $f(\eta)$ of (1) such that $(f(0), f'(0)) = (f_1, g_1) \in W_s$.  Using the theory of stable manifolds, we have thus rigorously proven the existence of the solutions required in the question as posted.  QED.

The preceding discussion provides demonstrations of the existence of solutions to (1) satisfying $\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = 0$, $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 1$ as required, but there is (at least) one remaining, tantalizing question concerning the flow of (1), (7) which, though strictly speaking not asked by the OP, is nevertheless worthy of a few remarks.  We have seen that there is a one-dimensional submanifold
$W_s(1, 0)$ of $\Bbb R^2$, the stable manifold of the critical point $(1, 0)$, such that $\phi_\eta((f_1, g_1)) \to (1, 0)$ as $\eta \to \infty$ for every $(f_1, g_1) \in W_s(1, 0)$; the question is, in broad terms, what happens to $(f_1, g_1) \in W_s(1, 0)$ under the action of the flow $\phi_\eta$, as $\eta \to -\infty$?  Since we have also seen that, for $(f_1, g_1) \in W_u(0, 0)$, the unstable manifold associated with the point $(0, 0)$, we have $\phi_\eta(f_1, g_1) \to (0, 0)$ as $\eta \to -\infty$,
it is tempting to conjecture that $W_s(1, 0)$ in fact meets $W_u(0, 0)$ at some point(s), which would in fact imply there is a trajectory $\gamma(\eta)$ of $F(f, g)$ which joins $(0, 0)$ and $(1, 0)$ in the sense that $\gamma(\eta) \to (0, 0)$ as $\eta \to -\infty$ and $\gamma(\eta) \to (1, 0)$ as $\eta \to \infty$.  If this were true, and I believe it to be, then a reasonably complete picture of the qualitative features of the flow $\phi_\eta$ could be had.  It is tempting for me to claim, as does Artem in his answer, that the two-dimensionality of $W_u(0, 0)$ is sufficient to guarantee $W_u(0, 0) \cap W_s(1, 0) \ne \varnothing$, but in the absence of a further analysis which rules out other possible phenomena such as periodic orbits I cannot with full confidence stand behind such an assertion.  But my nose and my gut tell it is so.

Well, I do believe I have typed enough; time to hit that old **POST** button!

Hope this helps!  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! The stable manifold theory thus shows us that solutions satisfying $\lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=1$ do in fact exist, a fact I thought I had already shown by assuming that the linearization behaves similarly to $f$ in the neighborhood of the critical points. It was interesting to read your explanation about this. The more I read answers and hints given the more I think that showing the existence of a connecting trajectory might be outside the scope of what is asked of me. Nonetheless, I want to know :) Thanks a lot for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

To make things slightly easier I consider the equation
$$u_t=u_{xx}+u(1-u),
$$
which can be obtained from the original one by scaling the spatial and temporal variables.

Now consider 
$$
u(x,t)=U(z)=U(x\pm ct),
$$
where I choose "plus", but "minus" is treated similarly. We have
$$
cU'=U(1-U)+U'',
$$
which can be rewritten as the system
$$
U'=V\\
V'=cV-U(1-U)
$$
with two equilibria: $O=(0,0)$ and $P=(1,0)$.

At $O$ the Jacobi matrix has two eigenvalues
$$
\lambda_{1,2}=\frac 12 (c\pm\sqrt{c^2-4}),
$$
which are not complex if $c\geq 2$ (we cannot have complex eigenvalues, hence this would mean that $U$ changes sign). Point $P$ is a saddle for any parameter values. This point has stable manifold with the direction $(-c,1)$ --- this is an eigenvector corresponding to the negative eigenvalue, hence pointing "north-west" from the point. This stable manifold has to cross the unstable manifold of $O$, since the latter is two dimensional, hence there is a unique homoclinic trajectory, connecting $O$ and $P$ and positive. This trajectory corresponds to the traveling wave solution of the original problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I can follow your explanation up to the last paragraph. Im just unsure of how we can prove that the fixed points $P$ and $O$ are connected. The theory behind manifolds and their stability is not something I am familiar with. Is there any easier (though possibly longer) way to show this? Thanks again for your answer!

Comment: @Slugger It helps when you write @ and name to see that you have a question. The easier way is plot the vector field around these points and realize that there is no other way for the vector field (which we know, strictly speaking, only around two points) to have a curve connecting these two points.

Comment: Added: you can see that the vector field when, say, $V=0$ and $0<U<1$ is directed "to the south", and in $V$ large enough, "to the north". There should be something that separates these two, and the general theory of dynamical systems tells us that this is exactly the heteroclinic trajectory.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess I hadn't typed quite enough!

In light of the extended discussion of notions surrounding stable manifold theory in both answers and in the comments, I wish to add a few remarks which further explicate, and hopefully clarify, the situation regarding its application to the problems presented in this question.  I am appending these "comments" as a separate answer, for two reasons:  i.)  they are probably too long to fit comfortably in even several comment boxes; and ii.)  inserting them *via* the editing process into my already-posted answer will take a *long, long* while, due to the time it takes the mathjax system to render long posts with substantial amounts of Latex.  So rather than strain my patience I beg the indulgence of my readers and continue the discussion in this, a separate answer to the OP's question.  This answer can and should, for all practical purposes, be considered of a piece with the one I previously posted.

These things being said . . .

As mentioned by Slugger in his comment on my previous answer, it is indeed the stable manifold theorem which affirms that the limiting behaviors of $F(f, g)$ and $DF$ are the same in the neighborhood of a critical point of $F$.  Without some result to this effect, there is no guarantee that the linear system will, in the limit, exhibit the same structure as the original, non-linearized equation(s).  A key observation here is that as long as the independent variable remains *finite*, i.e. we are only interested in $\eta$ in some bounded interval $(\eta_{\text{min}}, \eta_{\text{max}})$ with $-\infty < \eta_{\text{min}} < \eta_{\text{max}} < \infty$, then it is a relatively simple matter to affirm that the solutions of the linearized system stay arbitrarily close to those of the original one, provided they are initialized so and, again, the dependent variable is bounded.  This is if you will a standard, somewhat elementary result in the theory ODEs; a thorough discussion can by found, for example, in Chapter 17 of *Differential Equations, Dynamical Systems and and Introduction to Chaos*, by Morris Hirsch, Stephen Smale, and Robert L. Devaney; for a more advanced treatment see
Jack K. Hale's *Ordinary Differential Equations*, the citings in these books, or any of a number of other standard texts and references.  But it is the limiting cases as $\eta \to \pm \infty$ which require a more delicate approach, and this is what the theory of stable manifolds provides.

As for the existence of a heteroclinic trajectory $\gamma(\eta)$  "connecting" the equilibrium points of $F(f, g)$ in the sense that $\lim_{\eta \to -\infty} \gamma(\eta) = (0, 0)$ and $\lim_{\eta \to \infty} \gamma(\eta) = (1, 0)$, stable manifold theorems provide only a piece of the puzzle, for they are essentially *local* in nature; that is, they only give a detailed picture of $W_s$, $W_u$ in some neighborhood $U$ of the critical point to which they correspond.  Of course, such stable and unstable manifolds can be globalized by the action of $\phi_\eta$; for example, if $W_s$ is defined in a small neighborhood $U$ of a critical point, then the set

$\bigcup_{\eta \in \Bbb R} \phi_\eta(W_s) = \{(f, g) \in \Bbb R^2 \mid \phi_\eta(f, g) \in W_s \, \, \text{for some} \, \,\eta \in \Bbb R \}, \tag{1}$

consists of *all* points in $\Bbb R^2$ which $\phi_\eta$ takes into $W_s$, and hence eventually into the critical point associated with $W_s$ as $\eta \to \infty$.  But despite the fact that we can in principle *construct* global stable and unstable manifolds, in the sense of establishing their existence, we can't say much more about their properties without resorting to a more detailed, refined analysis of the vector field $F(f, g)$ and its flow $\phi_\eta$.  Indeed, it is possible, with a little effort and imagination, to describe a vector field $F_1(f, g)$ on $\Bbb R^2$ which has exactly the same critical point structure as $F(f, g)$, and even the same Jacobean matrices at these critical points, but for which there is no heteroclinic trajectory running between one critical point and the other.  To wit:

Let $F_1(f, g)$ have critical points at $(0, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$, as does $F(f, g)$, and suppose that in fact we arrange things so that $J_{F_1} = J_F$ at each of these points.  Consider the two circles $C_1$ and $C_2$ of radius $r_1$ and $r_2$ respectively, with $0 < r_1 < r_2 < 1$, both centered at $(0, 0)$, and further arrange things so that $F_1(f, g)$ is of constant magnitude and tangent to each of these circles, with the direction  of rotation the same on each.  Inside $C_1$, choose $F_1(f, g)$ differentiable so that, in addition to agreeing together with its Jacobean with $F(f, g)$ and its Jacobean at $(0, 0)$, the trajectories of $F_1(f, g)$ form spirals, as we approach $C_1$ from the inside, which converge to $C_1$ as $\eta \to \infty$.  In the annulur region between $C_1$ and $C_2$, choose $F_1(f, g)$ differentiable so that its trajectories spiral inward from $C_2$ and converge to $C_1$ as $\eta \to \infty$, and to $C_2$ as $\eta \to -\infty$; outside of $C_2$ choose $F_1(f, g)$ so that, near $C_2$, the trajectories spiral outward from $C_2$ and approach $C_2$ as $\eta \to -\infty$; in addition, outside of $C_2$ we arrange things so that exactly one of the orbits $\gamma(\eta)$ of $F_1(f, g)$ which "unwind from", that is to say, spiral outward from $C_2$, is in fact the stable manifold of $(1, 0)$;  that is, $\gamma(\eta) \to (1, 0)$ as $\eta \to \infty$; the other trajectories spiraling outward from $C_2$ wend off and become unbounded as they may.  What I have attempted to give here is a verbal description, albeit possibly a crude one, of the phase portrait of a system $(f', g')^T = F_1(f, g)$ which completely agrees with $(f', g')^T = F(f, g)$ insofar as critical point structure is concerned, but whose global trajectories exhibit radical differences from those of $(f', g')^T = F(f, g)$.  In particular, one should observe that (i.)  the unstable manifold of the point $(0, 0)$ is precisely the interior of the disk of radius $r_1$ centered at $(0, 0)$, the boundary of which is the circle $C_1$; and (ii.)  there is no heteroclinic trajectory of $F_1(f, g)$ connecting $(0, 0)$ and $(1, 0)$.  This illustrates the point that, even with the aid of stable manifold theory, the assessment of global orbit structure may be an arduous task, requireing much more work than the present answers present.  Finally, though my informal description of $F_1(f, g)$ and its flow ultimatley lacks rigor, I believe it is possible to analytically define $F_1(f, g)$ if sufficient care is taken, perhaps using partitions of unity in $\Bbb R^2$, but unfortunately I have neither the time nor space to present such a development here.  It is also unfortunate that I haven't given any pictures, undoubtedly worth several thousands of words in this context, but at present I lack the necessary graphics software to do so.

When I read our OP Slugger's question, I took the phrase "solutions satisfying $\lim_{x \to -\infty} f = 0$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f = 1$" to mean separate solutions of each type, rather than solutions satisfying both properties together.  And such we have show to exist; but the demonstration of the existence of a true heteroclinic integral curve of $(f', g')^T = F(f, g)$ is evidently a far more arduous task, one which makes me wonder just what level of experience and knowledge is assumed in the class for which this "little exercise" is homework.

Well, now I will attempt, once again, to stop typing, at least for the present.

And I really do hope this helps.  Once again I say, "Cheers!"

and once again, as always, I say

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: You write: "makes me wonder just what level of experience and knowledge is assumed in the class for which this "little exercise" is homework" -- In this type of exercises it is usually assumed that a vague description along the lines in my answer "by continuity we see.." is enough.

Comment: @Artem:  Now that I did not know . . . I took several pretty advanced courses in ODEs and PDEs when I was a student, back when the code of Hammurabi was first etched in clay tablets, and my subsequent adademic/industrial career was focused on modelling and simulation of dynamical systems, so I have had occasion to read many books an papers in the field.  In a sense, you could say I'm self-educated in these matters, by and large, so I'm not really in tune with current educational practices.  This is getting longish for a comment; to be continued . . .

Comment: @Artem:  By the way, did my somewhat hand-wavy attempt to describe the vector field $F_1(f, g)$ and its phase portrait in my second answer make sense to you?  I'd like the feedback.  And decent graphics SW!  In any event, not to put too fine a point on it, I believe it gives an example showing that we don't *necessarily* have $W_u(0, 0) \cap W_s(1, 0) \ne \varnothing$ in ODEs having the same critical point structure as the present instance, though I believe it to be true in this case.  Thanks for your attention to this matter.  Best, RKL.

Comment: No, of course these two manifolds do not have to intersect in general. However, for this (no intersection) to happen on the plane, they have to be separated by another manifold, emanating from another equilibrium, which is absent here. General theory tells us this is the only case. That is the primary reason there will be a connecting orbit. However, you are right, and a lot of this material is taught be hand waving. The difficulties can be appreciated if you think about Hilbert's 16th problem, for which we still, e.g., do not know an upper bound on the number of limit cycles in polynomial...

Comment: ...polynomial system of degree 2.

Comment: I think about Hilbert 16 far more than I can really afford to! ;-) ;-) ;-)!!!