# Analyzing the stability of equilibria

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, applications

There's a model with a condition $r>\mu$:

$$\begin{align}
S'&=r(S+I)-\beta SI-\mu S \\
I'&=\beta SI-(\mu +\alpha)I
\end{align}$$

I can easily see that the equilibria of the second equation are either $I=0$ or $\beta S=\mu +\alpha$. If $I=0$ the equilibria for the first equation is $rS=\mu S$. Since $r>\mu$ it must be the case that $S=0$. My textbook states, "the equilibrium  $(0,0)$ is unstable." I cannot see how though.

If the equilibrium is unstable the system moves away from the equilibrium. If stable the system moves towards the equilibrium. Since $(0,0)$ is an equilibrium for the system how can we gain any information about its stability since it makes the system equal zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with the given system of equations

$S'= r(S+I)-\beta SI-\mu S, \tag{1}$

$I'=\beta SI-(\mu +\alpha)I = I(\beta S - (\mu + \alpha)), \tag{2}$

we see that it indeed does have an equilibrium point at $(S, I) = (0, 0)$.  This means precisely that $S'(0, 0) = I'(0, 0) = 0$, as our OP SOULed_Outt has shown and as may readily be affirmed by direct substitution of $(S, I) = (0, 0)$ into (1)-(2).  Taking $S' = (dS/dt)$, $I' = (dI/dt)$, we see by unicity of solutions that the fact that $S'(0, 0) = I'(0, 0) = 0$ means that, if the system is initialized at $(0, 0)$, then the entire trajectory is given by $S(t) = I(t) = 0$ for all $t$.

The question of the *stability* of $(0, 0)$, however, addresses the issue of how trajectories initialized *near*, but *not at*, $(0, 0)$ behave as $t \to \infty$.  This question may often, *but not always*, be resolved by examining the linearization of  a given system at the equilibrium in question.  In the present case, we may compute such linearization by calculating the Jacobean matrix of (1)-(2) at $(0, 0)$.  We have, at any point $(S, I)$,

$J(S, I) = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{\partial S'}{\partial S} & \dfrac{\partial S'}{\partial I} \\ \dfrac{\partial I'}{\partial S} & \dfrac{\partial I'}{\partial I} \end{bmatrix}; \tag{3}$

we compute the partial derivatives by using (1), (2), finding

$\dfrac{\partial S'}{\partial S} = r - \mu -\beta I, \tag{4}$

$\dfrac{\partial S'}{\partial I} = r - \beta S, \tag{5}$

$\dfrac{\partial I'}{\partial S} = \beta I, \tag{6}$

$\dfrac{\partial I'}{\partial I} = \beta S - \mu - \alpha. \tag{7}$

When these four expressions are evaluated at $(S, I) = (0, 0)$ we find that

$J(0, 0) = \begin{bmatrix} r - \mu & r \\ 0 & -\mu - \alpha \end{bmatrix}. \tag{8}$

Now suppose we examine the eigenvalues of $J(0, 0)$; they satisfy the characteristic polynomial $p_J(\lambda)$, where

$p_J(\lambda) = \det (\begin{bmatrix} r - \mu - \lambda & r \\ 0 & -\mu - \alpha - \lambda \end{bmatrix}) = (r - \mu - \lambda)(-\mu -\alpha - \lambda). \tag{9}$

It is easily read off from (9) that the zeroes of $p_J(\lambda)$ occur at $\lambda_1 = r - \mu$, $\lambda_2 = -\mu - \alpha$.  Since $r > \mu$ by hypothesis, we see that $\lambda_1 > 0$; $\lambda_2$ may be positive, negative or zero depending on the relative values of $\mu$ and $\alpha$.  In the event that $\lambda_2 \ne 0$, then the matrix $J(0, 0)$ is known as *hyperbolic*, i.e. the eigevalues all have non-zero real parts.  In such a case we may invoke a major result, the so-called *stable manifold theorem*, which affirms that, in *some* neighborhood of $(0, 0)$, the solution set of (1), (2) is in fact well-described by the solution set of the system linearized about the equilibrium point $(0, 0)$; a more detailed discussion of this theorem, including linked references, may be found in my answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/535768/show-fvf-alpha2-f1-f-0-has-solutions-satisfying-lim-x-to-infty).  The linearized system is in fact

$\begin{pmatrix} S \\ I \end{pmatrix}' = J(0, 0)\begin{pmatrix} S \\ I \end{pmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} r - \mu & r \\ 0 & -\mu - \alpha \end{bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} S \\ I \end{pmatrix}; \tag{10}$

since $\lambda_1 > 0$, we see (intuitively; the stable manifold theorem lends rigor to this intuition) that any trajectory initialized sufficiently close to the line through $(0, 0)$ tangent to an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda_1$, which is in fact easily seen to be of the form $(k, 0)^T$ for $0 \ne k \in \Bbb R$, will in fact move away from $(0, 0)$ with increasing $t$; thus the equilibrium must be unstable.  When $\lambda_2 = 0$, we encounter a singular case which must be handled by more subtle methods; nevertheless the "eigensolution" to the linearized system $(S(t), I(t)) = e^{\lambda_1 t}(k, 0)$, which corresponds to the initial point $(k, 0)$ at $t = 0$, will still move away from $(0, 0)$ with increasing $t$, at least locally near $(0, 0)$, so the system apparently cannot be stable in this situation.

The geometrcal interpretation of this analysis is that, for $\lambda_2 >0$ , *any* point near $(0, 0)$ will be moved away from it by the flow; when $\lambda_2 < 0$, then $(0, 0)$ is a *saddle point*, and all the integral curves save two resemble hyperbolas, which may flow towards $(0, 0)$ for awhile but will eventually turn and head away.  The remaining two trajectories will approach $(0, 0)$ as $t \to \infty$, but from opposing directions; though do in fact "stabilize" to $(0, 0)$ as $t \to \infty$, they form a special case; the presence of the eigenvalue $\lambda_1 > 0$ implies that $(0, 0)$ is an unstable equilibrium point.

The information regarding the stability of $(0, 0)$ is encoded in the matrix $J(0, 0)$, *via* its eigenstructure; similar observations apply to any other critical points this system may possess, and indeed to the equilibria of general, nonlinear, autonomous ODEs.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: @SOULed_Outt:  Hey!  No problem!  Glad to help out!  And thanks for the "acceptance"!